# disable legend resizing of chart

Tags: highcharts

Does anyone know the setting in highcharts (I've looked through the API but I can't seem to find it - maybe looking in the wrong place?) where I can disable the chart's ability to resize when I click on a legend item?

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend

If there are two lines on the graph, and toggle off one of them on the legend, the graph resizes to show the one line full sized. I want to prevent this functionality.

Answer (score 7):

There actually is a simple solution to this provided for by the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.ignoreHiddenSeries):

```
chart: {
        ignoreHiddenSeries: false
   }
```

I'm pretty sure this is the behavior you desire.